# Recover the characteristic of $k$ from the category of $k$-varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, arithmetic-geometry, projective-varieties

Can you recover the characteristic of a perfect field from the category of smooth projective geometrically connected varieties over it?

Comment: There is a final object, and the covariant Yoneda functor of that object recovers the set of closed points.  Now we can formulate homogeneous objects.  There is a unique homogeneous variety where Aut is triply transitive.  Consider the p-torsion in the stabilizer of an ordered pair of distinct points.

Comment: Jason, does this work for fields that are not algebraically closed?

Comment: I was assuming that the field is algebraically closed . . .

Comment: Anyway, it's a really nice argument.

Comment: In the algebraically closed case, here is a variant bypassing the use of $\mathbb{P}^1$: $k$ has characteristic $p>0$ iff there is a group object $E$ such that the kernel of multiplication by $l$ on $E(k)$ has order $l^2$ for each prime $l\neq p$, and smaller order if $l=p$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Correction**. As correctly noted by Remy van Dobben de Bruyn, there is a mistake in Lemma 4.  What follows is a corrected argument, with the original (mistaken) post appended below the corrected argument.

Let $k$ be a perfect field.  Denote by $\mathbf{V}$ the category of $k$-schemes that are smooth, projective and geometrically connected.

**Proposition**.  A non-final object $Y$ of $\mathbf{V}$ is a curve if and only if the natural action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_2$ on $Y\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} Y$ admits a categorical quotient in $\mathbf{V}$.

**Proof**.  For a curve, the geometric quotient is smooth, hence it is an object of $\mathbf{V}$.

Let $Y$ be a non-final object that is not a curve.  Denote the dimension by $n\geq 2$.  In the category of $k$-schemes, there is a categorical quotient $Y_2$ (even a geometric quotient) of the action of $\mathfrak{S}_2$ on $Y\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}Y$, and it is singular along the image of the diagonal, i.e., the embedding dimension is strictly larger than $2n$.

There is a closed immersion of $Y_2$ into a projective space, and this is an object of $\mathbf{V}$.  Thus, if there is a categorical quotient $Z$, it factors this closed immersion.  In particular, the morphism from $Y_2$ to $Z$ is also a closed immersion of $k$-schemes.

Since the embedding dimension of $Y$ is strictly larger than $2n$, also $Z$ has dimension strictly larger than $2n$.  Thus, the closed immersion is not surjective on closed points.  For any closed point of $Z$ that is not in the image of $Y_2$, consider the blowing up $\widetilde{Z}$ of the categorical quotient at that closed point.  Since the field is perfect, $\widetilde{Z}$ is still a smooth $k$-scheme (this can fail for the blowing up at a closed point with inseparable residue field).

The closed immersion from $Y_2$ to $Z$ factors through the morphism $\widetilde{Z}\to Z$.  Of course the identity map on $Z$ does not factor through $\widetilde{Z}$.  This contradicts that $Z$ is a categorical quotient. **QED**

Now we repeat the last part of the argument from the original post.

**Lemma**.  A $k$-curve $Y$ in $\mathbf{V}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ if and only if every $k$-curve in $\mathbf{V}$ admits a nonconstant morphism to $Y$.

**Proof**.  This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ admits no nonconstant morphism to a curve of positive genus, and every $k$-curve of genus $0$ with a $k$-point is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$. **QED**

**Corollary**.  The field $k$ is uniquely determined by the category $\mathbf{V}$.

**Proof**.  The proposition and the lemma together establish that there is a characterization of the object $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ in $\mathbf{V}$ in purely categorical terms.  The automorphism group of $(\mathbb{P}^1_k,0,\infty)$ is $k^\times$.  The automorphism group of $(\mathbb{P}^1,\infty)$ is a semidirect product of $k^\times$ and the additive group $k$.  With the structure of both the multiplicative group of $k$ and the additive group of $k$, we can recover the field $k$.  **QED**

**Original post.**  There is a mistake in Lemma 4, as pointed out by Remy van Dobben de Bruyn.

I am writing an answer to address the case of a field $k$ that is not necessarily algebraically closed.  Denote by $\mathbf{V}$ the category of $k$-schemes that are smooth, projective and geometrically connected.

**Lemma 1**.  The $k$-scheme $\text{Spec}\ k$ is a final object in $\mathbf{V}$.

**Proof**.  In fact this is a final object in the larger category of all $k$-schemes. **QED**

**Definition 2**.  A morphism in $\mathbf{V}$ is **constant** if it factors through a morphism from the domain to a final object.

**Definition 3**.  For an object $Z$ of $\mathbf{V}$, an ordered pair $(f,g)$ of nonconstant morphisms, $f:X\to Z$ and $g:Y\to Z$, is **cofinite** if every ordered pair $(u,v)$ of morphisms $u:W\to X$, $v:W\to Y$ with $f\circ u$ equal to $g\circ v$ is a pair of constant morphisms.

**Lemma 4**.  A non-final object of $\mathbf{V}$ is a $k$-curve if and only if there exists no cofinite pair of nonconstant morphisms to the object.

**Proof**.  This is a straightforward application of Bertini-type theorems. **QED**

**Lemma 5**.  A $k$-curve $Y$ in $\mathbf{V}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ if and only if every $k$-curve in $\mathbf{V}$ admits a nonconstant morphism to $Y$.

**Proof**.  This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ admits no nonconstant morphism to a curve of positive genus. **QED**

**Proposition 6**.  The field $k$ is uniquely determined by the category $\mathbf{V}$.

**Proof**.  The lemmas establish that there is a characterization of the object $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ in $\mathbf{V}$ in purely categorical terms.  The automorphism group of $(\mathbb{P}^1_k,0,\infty)$ is $k^\times$.  The automorphism group of $(\mathbb{P}^1,\infty)$ is a semidirect product of $k^\times$ and the additive group $k$.  With the structure of both the multiplicative group of $k$ and the additive group of $k$, we can recover the field $k$.  **QED**

Comment: In Lemma 5, two words should be said about genus $0$ curves without rational points. (Do rational points play a role in Def 3/Lemma 4 as well?)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn  You are correct!  That lemma was wrong :(  I am revising my answer now . . .